# MVC 4 Best practice to hide client id's on front end

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to .net world so please be patient. I have a requirement of displaying a list of users in a view from controller (MVC4 application with razor engine).

When users are displayed in a view, a client can click on a link and get particular user information on a separate view.  I want to implement this but want to hide any particular client Id from user. Client Id will be used server side to retrieve client info.

I can do this in several ways for eg: in the links I can put a data-Id and then use this id in server side to retrieve more info from DB. My concern is that a client can simply see these id from HTML source and type controller url with this id information. I also don't like hidden fields.

So my question is what are other different ways or best practices to implement such functionality ?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers. They helped in one or the other way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using keys in the fashion you describe is fairly common to navigate around an application.

If you're worried about security (someone being able to pass a discovered or guessed key to an action on a controller and see some information they should not) then validate user context at the controller/action level before returning information from the action and decide not to return secure information if you deem it inappropriate.

The only other way I can imagine allowing the UI to speak back to your server side with a semblance of necessary context information might be to generate surrogate guid fields for each critical piece of data sent down to your client, using that surrogate to send back to your server side, translating the guid back to the real key and then going about your business.  (GUIDs would not be reasonably as guessble as ints, per se.)  However, I would never do such a thing...

Think about the problem you're trying to solve and make sure it warrants this sort of complexity.

Comment: I agree in checking user context approach. Thanks for your answer n time.

Answer (score 0):

Concur with all above - if you are providing a user interface to view detailed info based on an ID, you can't hide that ID - you have to post it back.  It may not be the actual ID (i.e. a GUID), but that is irrelevant.  You are providing, client side, an ID that anyone can use to retrieve detail based on the ID.

Ask yourself the question, "I want to provide a phonebook, but not show phone numbers.  Can I do that?"

Comment: True, but often there is a concern about the ease with which new IDs can be guessed. Using GUIDs instead of integers doesn't address the issue of controlling authorized access to objects, but it does make it harder to guess the IDs of unseen objects.